# iOS Load Modal View Top to Bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I was wondering if anyone has every loaded a modal view controller from the top to the bottom instead of if popping up from the bottom to the top?
Loading normally from bottom to top:

```
       [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

One solution seems that you could create a view and animate yourself from top to bottom, but I was looking to do it with a view controller and was hoping I did not overlook anything when I reviewed the modalTransitionalStyles.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: I guess that you got to pop and push.

Comment: Pop and Push? I dont follow?

Comment: You have to do it yourself, there is no standard transition like that.

Comment: OK thats what I figured, any idea how I would approach that?  Possibly animate a view from top to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is subclass UIStoryboard segue and make a custom animation that goes from top to bottom, and then present the view controller using that segue.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for the answer, I forgot to say, that I'm not using storyboard, but nibs instead.